# webpack error - you may need a appropriate loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack

When I ran `npm run watch` got the following error. Can any one tell me the reason.

```
ERROR in ./~/praxis/src/index.js
Module parse failed: /home/iswan/os-projects/praxis-samples/03-forms/node_modules/praxis/src/index.js Line 1: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| export { default as React } from 'react';
| export * from 'react-router';
| 
 @ ./src/main.js 5:14-31
```

File that showing erro

```
export { default as Dispatcher } from './app/Dispatcher';
export { default as Session } from './app/Session';

export { default as MenuBar } from './ui/MenuBar';
export { default as Input } from './ui/Input';

export { default as ArrayStore } from './storage/ArrayStore';
export { default as RESTApi } from './net/RESTApi';
```

Comment: You need to run your stuff through a loader like babel.

Comment: I'm already running it with babel

Comment: Can you show your Babel loader specific configuration? It might not be picking up your file correctly.

Comment: Anyway please attach your webpack config.

Comment: I came here because I'm seeing the same error for the first time in a large project and it seems illogical...could be a Webpack or Babel bug